# How to make child entity appear after soft delete its parent entity TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have those entities:

```
class Parent extends BaseEntity{

        @Column()
        name:string

        @OneToMany(
           ()=>Child,
           (Child)=>Child.Parent
        )
        Child:Child[]

        @DeleteDateColumn()
        deletedAt?: Date;

}

class Child extends BaseEntity{

        @Column()
        name:string

        @ManyToOne(
            ()=>Parent,
            (Parent)=>Parent.Child
        )
        Parent:Parent

}
```

when I soft delete the parent, the children also got soft delete I do not want they to get soft deleted.
I tried to add Constants like:

```
  {
      onDelete:"NO ACTION",
      orphanedRowAction:"nullify",
  }
```

It does not help, I also tried to get the children by `withDeleted()` with I call `createQueryBuilder()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to soft delete the children use `parentRepo.softDelete(e.id)`, not `parentRepo.softRemove(e)`